# Confusing gcc error message in simple macro expansion

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

I've been looking at this too long and just can't see what the problem is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} S;

#define F(a,b) ( v.a = a, v.b = b, v )

int main(void) {
    S s, v;

    s = ( v.a = 1, v.b = 2, v ); // this works as expected

    printf("s = { %d %d } \n", s.a, s.b);

    s = F(1, 2); // but gcc complains about the macro equivalent

    printf("s = { %d %d } \n", s.a, s.b);

    return 0;
}
```

gcc complains:

> In function 'main':
>       Line 17: error: expected identifier before numeric constant

The two assignments should be the same after pre-processing but evidently I'm missing something...

You can run the code here: http://codepad.org/0c1aUBLm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define F(a,b) ( v.a = a, v.b = b, v )
```

When called with 1 and 2 as arguments, this expands to

```
( v.1 = 1, v.2 = 2, v)
```

Change the argument names of the macro to something different:

```
#define F(first,second) ( v.a = first, v.b = second, v )
```

Comment: D'oh - I knew it had to be something simple and obvious but I just couldn't see it - thanks...

Comment: @PaulR I'm assuming you are very tired :) Get some coffee/sleep :)

Comment: You are spot on - brain function severely depleted just now. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Won't `F(1, 2)` expand to `( v.1 = 1, v.2 = 2, v )` ?

```
#define F(x,y) ( v.a = x, v.b = y, v )
```

should be better

Comment: Thanks @simonc - H2CO3 narrowly beat you to the answer but have an up-vote anyway... ;)